# get_avatar wordpress image never displaying but appears in console

Tags: php, wordpress

i am trying to use get_avatar function in wordpress, and i am getting the tag img in console but the image is not showing in browser with notice array to string conversion,

Here is the code :

```
 <?php

      $args = array(
        'role'    => 'editor',
        'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
        'order'   => 'ASC'
    );

    $users = get_users( $args );

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $users as $user ) {
        echo '<li>' . esc_html( $user->display_name ) . '<br>' . '[' . esc_html( $user->user_description ) . ']' . '</li>';

        echo get_avatar($user->ID ,null, false, array('scheme' => 'http'));
    }

    echo '</ul>';

  ?>
```

The screenshot is :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxwKr.png

I also try https instead of http, it also never works.
When i use var_dump like this:

```
  var_dump( get_avatar($user->ID ,null, false, array('scheme' => 'http')));
```

The screenshot is :
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2ph4.png]

Comment: The fourth parameter of that function is supposed to be the `alt` text for the image - you passed `array('scheme' => 'http')` for that, but as $args that should be the _fifth_ parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `get_avatar` takes 5 parameters and you are only giving it 4. You are missing the `$alt` param that gets put on the image tag as an attribute.

```
get_avatar($user->ID , 96,'', 'Alt Image Text Here', array('scheme' => 'http'));
```

[WP get_avatar() Docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar/)

Comment: Hello, i put echo get_avatar($user->ID ,98,'','avatar', array('scheme' => 'http'));

Comment: I updated my answer. There were improper types for the `$size` and `$default` params

Comment: Do you mean like this ;

Comment: get_avatar($user->ID , '96',' ', 'Alt Image Text Here', array('scheme' => 'http'));